# Amazon Mechanical Turk 'custom' submit via web interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

Is there any way to trigger the submit form on Mechanical Turk via a button which isn't their provided 'submit' button? (I require it to submit an empty form to speed up workers time)

I've tried this:
`$('#mturk_form').submit();` but a "There was a problem submitting this HIT" warning/error returns.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do anything you want to cause the POST to the submit endpoint (e.g. `https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit`). Adding a `assignmentId` param is required, but other than that, it's a standard form submit.

The trick is that you need to pass a param `assignmentId` when you submit. The value for this field is set in a query string param when the page loads. (The assignment id lets MTurk know which worker did which piece of work, so it's different everytime a worker views one of your HITs.) Similarly, the form action URL changes between sandbox and prod, so the best practice is to read from the query string param `turkSubmitTo` and POST back to that location.

If you're comfortable with JavaScript, read over the "helper" script to see what it's doing: https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js

Also, see this answer for a similar question: [How do I define what the "submit" button returns on Mechanical Turk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246928)