# How do I define what the "submit" button returns on Mechanical Turk?

Tags: javascript, html, mechanicalturk

I'm writing my own HIT template for `mTurk` with `HTML / JavaScript` (editing the source section). `MTurk's` format for workers' response is an excel file with various parameters (such as `assignment ID`, `worker ID`, etc.). I'm having trouble finding out how do modify this returned excel file, in order to include my own custom parameters in it.

**To simplify, my code is:**

```
<html>
      <script type="text/javascript">
           //many functions
           var myObject = {};
           //event listeners add attributes to myObject
      </script>
</html>
```

The answer to my `HIT` is the content of `myObject`, so I need to link it to the submit button and add it to the outputted excel file.

Answer (score 0):

When using [HTMLQuestion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle.html), your template is the one creating the submit button. When the submit button is clicked, you need to cause that to POST the contents of `myObject` to the external submit endpoint (e.g. `https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit`). To do that, you could follow a recipe like this: [POST data in JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255948/post-data-in-json-format)